# 4 level ExpandableListView- 4th level opens underneath the 2nd level, doesn't shift it

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been trying to create a simple 4-level expandable listview. It works perfectly for 3-levels but when I add 4th level it messes up. 4th level list opens but shifts only 3rd level list, not the 2nd and 1st level. So 4th and 3rd level list disappears under the 2nd level.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int FIRST_LEVEL_COUNT = 5;
    public static final int SECOND_LEVEL_COUNT = 5;
    public static final int THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT = 5;
    public static final int FOURTH_LEVEL_COUNT = 5;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(new ParentLevel(this));
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Parent(First) Level




    public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public ParentLevel(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
            secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context));
            secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
            return secondLevelELV;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return SECOND_LEVEL_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return FIRST_LEVEL_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
                text.setText("FIRST LEVEL");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }





    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Second Level


    public class SecondLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

        public SecondLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations.
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }





    public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public SecondLevelAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
                text.setText("SECOND LEVEL");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ThirdLevelExpandableListView thirdLevelELV = new ThirdLevelExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
            thirdLevelELV.setAdapter(new ThirdLevelAdapter(context));
            thirdLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
            return thirdLevelELV;

        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Third Level


    public class ThirdLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

        public ThirdLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations.
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public class ThirdLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public ThirdLevelAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
                text.setText("THIRD LEVEL");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            FourthLevelExpandableListView fourthLevelELV = new FourthLevelExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
            fourthLevelELV.setAdapter(new FourthLevelAdapter(context));
            fourthLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
            return fourthLevelELV;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return FOURTH_LEVEL_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }





    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fourth Level


    public class FourthLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

        public FourthLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations.
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }




    public class FourthLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public FourthLevelAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fourth, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
                text.setText("FOURTH LEVEL");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fourth, null);
                TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
                text.setText("FOURTH LEVEL");
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return FOURTH_LEVEL_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/mainList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

row_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="100dp"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventsListEventRowText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventsListEventRowText"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_third.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventsListEventRowText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row_fourth.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#d6cf1e">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventsListEventRowText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem here and solution also.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android useful for n level tree list.

Comment: Have you tried this? I can't get this one working too.

Comment: You'll have to customize it I mean the look and fill. It works perfectly and its gonna take lot time to understand and customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, even according to your requirement you can manage number of levels,

https://github.com/triggs/NLevelExpandableListView

Comment: If you post URL's try posting a little code sample to explain what the url is about. Otherwise it will be seen as spam and make your answer less credible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).